# Recovering chain from a backup

Tags: grandpa, block-production, finality, finalization

Prerequisites:

1. A small subset of validators controlled by my company and a much larger set of external validators.
2. A backup of the `db` folder was created 4 hours (1 epoch) before an incident.

Incident:

1. After a runtime upgrade with missed migration, a chain has stopped producing blocks.

Our plan

1. Set up a firewall to prevent internal validators from syncing with a corrupted state.
2. Restore internal validators from the backup.
3. Coordinate external validators to clean their state and join the internal network.

Problem:

1. After restoring the internal validator from the backup they can produce the blocks but not finalize due to this error:

```
2024-02-28 14:49:04 a defensive failure has been triggered; please report the block number at https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues: NodeNotFound
2024-02-28 14:49:04 [#14456580]   Failed to finalize election round. reason ElectionError::Fallback("`NoElection` cannot do anything.")
```

2. We have reset `type Fallback` to on-chain execution and performed a runtime upgrade. Right after that, we called `election_multi_provider::governance_fallback` but block production stopped because of `Unexpected epoch change`.

Question:

1. Do you have any ideas on making the internal validators produce and finalize the blocks?